# schema.org itemprop="image" and google snippet / excerpt

Tags: schema.org

I've implemented schema.org's Product in an e-commerce site, and I have a question about image sizes and image proportions.

The only information I can find about the image property is that google can choose not to use the image if it has the wrong proportion or wrong size.

What is a good proportion and a good size for these images?

Comment: Good question. I'd like an answer to this too.